# Branching process and characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The following problem is from an old exam:

> Consider a branching process with one ancestor. The offspring of this
>   ancestor is called the first generation. Suppose that the
>   characteristic function of the offspring distribution is
>   $\varphi_Y(t)= \frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{it}}$ for some $0<p<1$. What is the
>   probability that there are still some individuals in the third
>   generation?

I know that if X(n)= # individuals in the n:th generation, X(1) has the same distribution as Y. I also know that $\sum_{k=1}^{X(n-1)}Y_k = X(n)$ (that it is a random sum). However I'm not really sure how to go about this.
Can someone help me solving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be the moment generating function (mgf) of the offspring distribution: 
$f(z)=\mathbb Ez^Y$. Since $\varphi_Y(t)=\mathbb Ee^{itY}$, we have
$$
f(e^{it})=\varphi_Y(t)=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{it}}, \quad f(z)=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)z}.
$$
Denote by $f_1(z)=f(z)$ the mgf of $X(1)$ which is the same as mgf of $Y$.

Let us find mgf of $X(2)$. By Total Probability Law
$$
f_2(z)=\mathbb Ez^{X_2}=\mathbb Ez^{\sum_{k=1}^{X(1)}Y_k} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\mathbb P(X(1)=j)\, \mathbb E\left[z^{\sum_{k=1}^{X(1)}Y_k}\bigm| X(1)=j\right]
$$
Find the last expectation first. Independence of $X(1)$ and $Y_k$ in the above sum leads to
$$
\mathbb E\left[z^{\sum_{k=1}^{X(1)}Y_k}\bigm| X(1)=j\right] = 
\mathbb E\left[z^{\sum_{k=1}^{j}Y_k}\right]= \mathbb Ez^{Y_1}\cdot\dots\cdot \mathbb E z^{Y_j}=\left(f_1(z)\right)^j.
$$
Let's return to $f_2(z)$:
$$
f_2(z)= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(f_1(z)\right)^j \cdot \mathbb P(X(1)=j) = f_1(f_1(z)).
$$

Doing the same for $f_3(z)=\mathbb Ez^{X_3}$ we get 
$$f_3(z)=f_1(f_2(z))=f_1(f_1(f_1(z))).$$

The proability that there are still some individuals in the third generation is exactly the probability that $X_3\neq 0$. Note that for any r.v. $X$ taking integer nonnegative values, $\mathbb P(X=0)=f(0)$, where $f(z)$  is mgf of $X$. Indeed,
$$
f(z)=\mathbb Ez^X = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^j \mathbb P(X=j)= \mathbb P(X=0)+z\mathbb P(X=1)+z^2\mathbb P(X=2)+\ldots. $$
If we set $z=0$ in this equality, we vanish all summands in r.h.s. except of $\mathbb P(X=0)$.

Finally, we need to calculate 
$$
\mathbb P(X_3>0)=1- \mathbb P(X_3=0)=1-f_3(0)=1-f_1(f_1(f_1(0))).
$$
Here $f_1(0)=\tfrac{p}{1-(1-p)\cdot 0}= p$, 
$$f_1(f_1(0))=f_1(p)=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)p},$$ and finally 
$$
f_1(f_1(f_1(0))) = f_1\left(\color{red}{\frac{p}{1-(1-p)p}}\right) = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)\color{red}{\frac{p}{1-(1-p)p}}}
$$

The required probability is
$$
\mathbb P(X_3>0)=1-\frac{p}{1-(1-p){\frac{p}{1-(1-p)p}}}=\frac{(1-p)^3}{1+2p^2-2p},
$$
if I'm not mistaken in simplifying the last fraction.